# Way to bypass validation with custom cloning

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I have a scenario whenever any field on opportunity is edited , i am checking if OpportunityContactRole is present or not. If it is not present then i am throwing an error to user saying to add OpportunityContactRole. There is a custom cloning on Opportunity, during this custom cloning many fields on opportunity are updated from Opportunity LineItem.
Whenever i am cloning the record , i am stuck at the validation . What is the best way to bypass the validation when cloning. Below is the code which i am using in before Update on Opportunity

```
 List<OpportunityContactRole> lstOcr = new  List<OpportunityContactRole>();
    Boolean checkEmptyRole = false;
    Boolean isChanged = false;
    Boolean isCloned = false;
    public void validateIfOCRisPresent(List<Opportunity> opportunityRecords, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap) {
        system.debug('opportunityRecords ' + opportunityRecords);
        for(OpportunityContactRole ocr: [SELECT Id, Role FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId IN :opportunityRecords]) {
            lstOcr.add(ocr);
            If(ocr.Role != null) {
                checkEmptyRole = true;
            }
        }
        if(lstOcr.size() == 0 || checkEmptyRole) {
            Opportunity oppObject = new Opportunity(); 
            Schema.SObjectType objType = oppObject.getSObjectType(); 
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mapFields = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fields.getMap(); 
            for(Opportunity opp : opportunityRecords){ 
                Opportunity oldOPP = oldMap.get(opp.Id);
                for (String str : mapFields.keyset()) {
                    if(str == 'createddate' && oldOPP.get('createddate') == null) { 
                        isCloned = true;
                    }
                }

            }
            system.debug('isChanged' + isChanged);
            for (Opportunity opp : opportunityRecords) {  
                if(isCloned){
                    
                }else{
                   opp.addError (Label.OCREmptyCheck); 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate class with static variable and you can use the same state through out the transaction.

```
public class MaintainState{
     public static Boolean checkIfInsert = false;
}
```

In your trigger you can update the static variable during insert and using in the below way might resolve your issue.

```
public class TriggerHelperClass{
 public void helperMethod(){
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
            MaintainState.checkIfInsert = true;
    }

    if(Trigger.isUpdate()){
        List<OpportunityContactRole> lstOcr = new  List<OpportunityContactRole>();
        .
        .
        . your logic
        if(!MaintainState.checkIfInsert)
            opp.addError(Label.OCREmptyCheck);
        }
    }
}
```